# OpenLayers 3/GeoJSON - Feature 'source'?

Tags: openlayers, geojson, features

I'm fresh with OpenLayers/GeoJSON...

Anyway, vector layer with features (lines, polygons, points...) and it pulls those data from GeoJSON ("type":"FeatureCollection") file.

Is there a way to see 'feature source' etc. when I click on line, can I find where is the code behind it that 'draws' that line?

My goal is to be able to tell "ok, I have clicked this and it is controlled by this peace of code... or nearby".

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no way to get a reference to a source from a feature.
You can implement a piece of code that checks if a given source contains a feature.